# How to record each command's duration/result and display this information with `history`?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I have some commands that take a really long time to run. I'd like to be able to keep track of all of them in history.

I've looked into history flags, but those seem to only show the time/date the command started and the status code.

Comment: I would make a wrapper for your long commands with the time(1) utility. It has feature rich logging functionality. With bash, use the full path to it, otherwise you'll get the limited bash builtin version.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answering your question, here is a function I have in my `.zshrc` to send a desktop notification when a command took more than 10 s.

You may adapt to build your own history file.

(To have the notifications, you must have notify-send or adapt `$notifier`)

```
notifier=notify-send
if [[ ${TERM[1,5]} == xterm ]]; then
    preexec() {
        notifiable_cmd=$1
        notifiable_start_time=`date +%s`
    }

    precmd() {
        if (( $? == 0 )); then
            notifiable_status="Success in "
        else
            notifiable_status="Failed in "
        fi
        if [[ "$notifiable_cmd" != "" ]]; then
            (( notifiable_time = `date +%s` - $notifiable_start_time ))
            if [[ $notifiable_time -ge 60 ]]; then
                notifiable_str_time="$(($notifiable_time%100000/60)) min $(($notifiable_time%60)) s"
            else
                notifiable_str_time="$notifiable_time[1,5] s"
            fi
            if [[ $notifiable_time -gt 10 ]]; then
                $notifier $notifiable_cmd "$notifiable_status $notifiable_str_time"
            fi
        fi
        notifiable_cmd=
    }
fi
```

(Adapted from this article [Growl upon job completion in zsh](https://contrapunctus.net/blog/2009/growl-upon-completion) on contrapunctus.net)